# How to repeatedly handle an exception until proper result?

Tags: ruby, exception, rescue

I have a custom exception that I want raised and rescued for as many times as performing the method causes the error.  I know that it will eventually result in a exception free result.

Using begin/rescue/end it seems like when the exception is thrown and the rescue block invoked, if the exception is thrown again the program leaves the begin/rescue/end block and the error ends the program.  How can I keep the program running until the proper result is reached?  Also, am I incorrect on my thinking of what's happening?

Here's basically what I want to happen (but obviously with as DRY of code as possible...this code is just to illustrate and not what I'd implement).

```
ships.each do |ship|
  begin
    orientation = rand(2) == 1 ? :vertical : :horizontal
    cell_coords = [rand(10), rand(10)] 
    place_ship(ship, orientation, cell_coords)
  rescue OverlapError  #if overlap error happens twice in a row, it leaves?
    orientation = rand(2) == 1 ? :vertical : :horizontal
    cell_coords = [rand(10), rand(10)] 
    place_ship(ship, orientation, cell_coords)
  rescue OverlapError
    orientation = rand(2) == 1 ? :vertical : :horizontal
    cell_coords = [rand(10), rand(10)] 
    place_ship(ship, orientation, cell_coords)
  rescue OverlapError
    orientation = rand(2) == 1 ? :vertical : :horizontal
    cell_coords = [rand(10), rand(10)] 
    place_ship(ship, orientation, cell_coords)
  #keep rescuing until the result is exception free
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `retry`:

```
ships.each do |ship|
  begin
    orientation = rand(2) == 1 ? :vertical : :horizontal
    cell_coords = [rand(10), rand(10)] 
    place_ship(ship, orientation, cell_coords)
  rescue OverlapError  #if overlap error happens twice in a row, it leaves?
    retry
  end
end
```

Anyway, I have to say that you should not use exceptions as control flow. I will recommend you , if `place_ship` is expected to fail, it should return `true`/`false` result, and you should include the code in a standard `do while` loop.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Both answered my question and sparked me to a better way to implement.